# $\exp(i \theta)=1?$

Tags: exponential-function

So I was thinking,
$\exp(i\theta) = \exp( i\theta\cdot2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi})$, we can rearrange it, so that:

\begin{align}
& \exp\left( i\theta\cdot2\pi\cdot\frac{1}{2\pi}\right)=\exp\left(2\pi i\cdot\frac{\theta}{2\pi}\right)=\exp(2\pi i)^{\theta/(2\pi)} \\[8pt]
= {} & (\exp(\pi i)^2)^{\theta/(2\pi)}=((-1)^2)^{\theta/(2\pi)}=1^{\theta/(2\pi)}=1
\end{align}

Can someone tell me what went wrong?

Comment: You need to be careful when taking complex roots or you can do something similar and get $(\sqrt{-1})^2=1$ by say, the following: $\sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1}=1.$ What went wrong is $x^\frac{a}{b}\neq (x^{a})^\frac{1}{b}$ in general with complex roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
e^{(ab)} \overset{\text{?}}{=} (e^a)^b 
$$

The equality above is true and $a$ and $b$ are real.  Your example shows that it doesn't always work when they are complex but not real.

And that holds for other bases than $e$ as well.  Consider $1^{1/3}$.  Certainly that should mean a cube root of $1$, since $1^{1/3}\cdot1^{1/3}\cdot1^{1/3}$ should be $1^{1/3+1/3+1/3}=1^1$.  But there are three different complex cube roots of $1$.  Which one is it?